OrderBy method does not work after EF Core 3.1 upgrade
public virtual async Task<IPagedList<TEntity>> PageAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> sortingKeySelector = null,
    SortingOrder sortingOrder = SortingOrder.Ascending,
    string include = "", int pageIndex = 1, int pageSize = 1000)
{
    // ....

    query = sortingOrder == SortingOrder.Ascending
        ? query.OrderBy(sortingKeySelector)
        : query.OrderByDescending(sortingKeySelector);

    var result = await Paged(query, pageIndex, pageSize).ToListAsync();

    // ...
}

I get this exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet
.Where(r => False || r.IsDeleted == False)
.OrderBy(r => r.Name)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Does anyone have similar problem and how can be resolved?

What i s the invocation method when the exception happens? I mean, how sortingKeySelector is defined - it must be "translatable" for EF, and i guess it is not.

This is how it is used: var religions = await _religionRepository.PageAsync(sortingKeySelector: l => l.Name);

Remove parts of that Linq Expression until it translates. Then, the last that you removed is the first you need to fix. After that: rinse, repeat.

There's just not enough details here for us to help with. On the surface, this code should work fine, so I suspect there is some code you have omitted that is causing the problem. First we have no idea what query is and what else happens to it. Secondly, what does the Paged class actually to too?

I believe you're running into the
High-Impact breaking change for EF Core 3.0.
Basically EF Core 3 made a clean break between the portions of a linq query that have a sql translation and the portion that must be evaluated client side.  As of 3.0, mixing the two will throw an exception.
You'll need to rewrite the query.
